# Nuxt/image-edge Image links broken

Tags: nuxtjs3

I can't seem to get NuxtJS image optimization to work properly. I have put the images I want to link into my `static/images` directory, and am linking to them as `<nuxt-img src="/images/image.jpeg">` to refer to `static/images/image.jpeg`.

However, on my web page with `pnpm run dev`, the generated link seems to be to `_ipx/_/_nuxt/static/images/image.jpeg`, while the images are under *actually* under `_nuxt/static/images/image.jpeg` (without `_ipx/_`). What might be my problem? I was also expecting the names to be `image-[some hash].jpeg` and not just the same name if the optimizer were working correctly.

However, if I run `pnpm generate` instead of `pnpm run dev`, the optimized images can be found in `dist/_nuxt/image-[hash].jpeg` (with the hash afterwards!), but the link in the html still refers to `/_ipx/_/_nuxt/image-[hash].jpeg`! How do I fix this problem properly?

Here's the relevant part of my nuxt config:

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    modules: [
        '@nuxt/image-edge',
    ],
    buildModules: [
        '@nuxt/image-edge'
    ],
    image: {
        // Options
    }
})
```

I'm using Nuxt 3.3.2 and @nuxt/image-edge 1.0.0-28001428.0aa03b6

I'm a complete newbie to this so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A couple of notes:

- As mentioned in the docs, static generation is not reliable yet: https://v1.image.nuxtjs.org/advanced/static-images
- That module is far from usable. I don't know why they advertise it, but it's clearly not ready for production, and there is very scarse activity from the nuxt team on updating it (look at the gigantic amount of open issues with no activity). I'd recommend avoid using it for the time being, hopefully at some point they'll dedicate to it the required attention.